# Error: Source Path does not exist for android icon png when building for ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

I am trying to use `ionic platform add android` to create an android project, but it always complains that `resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png` does not exist. In fact it doesn't -- none of these resources exist. They can get created by `ionic resources`.

*However* if I try to run `ionic resources` without the platform, I am told to add the platform first. This leads me to essentially do something like:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic resources
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android
```

*Then* it works properly. Is there anything I can do to make sure the resources get properly built or referenced before adding the platform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This actually had to do with my configuration. If you don't specify the platform in your configuration, `platform add` will create one for you. This automatically includes paths to resources that may not be there.

Update your config.xml to include the platform; even if it is empty:

```
<platform name="android"/>
<platform name="ios"/>
```

Then, `platform add` will not update the platform in the config and look for resources that may not be there. You still should do `ionic resources` to generate them after the fact, though.

Answer (score 17):

For me, in config.xml, path had backward slash in  tag, changed it from:

```
<icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
```

to:

```
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
```

Comment: With me, it was the other way around (developing on Windows), so I changed "/" to "\" and the problem was gone!

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a `config.xml` path issue.

Before I had this:

```
<icon density="hdpi" src="res/android/ic-hdpi.png" />
```

but in my folder structure I have an extra folder called **icon**, so I change all the `.png` path files to:

```
<icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/ic-hdpi.png" />
```

and it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

For me, this issue was due to below line in config.xml:

```
'<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />'
```

Actually when you try to add any platform using "ionic cordova platform add android/ios", it will add respective platform and generates respective resources("icon.png" and "splash.png"). With portrait orientation, it will add only relevant resources to that orientation(i.e. ionic cordova resources does not add the landscape images if the orientation is set to portrait) and fails with "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" error.
Hence please check whether your config.xml have any preference for portrait/landscape mode.

```
Please remove any preference with portrait/landscape from your config.xml file before adding platform.
```

Comment: When you using only portrait mode than it only generates the resources for portrait not for landscape. But when we build the project it does require all resources. Removing orientation mode from config.xml does the trick . :)

Answer (score 2):

For Ionic this works for me:

```
npm i -g cordova-res
ionic cordova resources --cordova-res
```

found here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3762#issuecomment-456967033

Think it's an mac/windows-issue.

Answer (score 0):

may be while creating the ionic app resources not added properly simply you can do one thing install another app by using following command.

```
ionic start appname blank
```

then copy the android icons folder and paste into you current app folder this will work fine.the image missed in your project is 72*72 image.please check the resources once.

Comment: I want to use a custom icon that gets built from the resources, though

Comment: ok add that custom image name in the place of  drawable-hdpi-icon.png in the config.xml file or else change the name of the custom image name to drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the splash screen and app icon. I mistaken in the name of the files. In my case the error was due to the invalid file names. I just copied and pasted the assets i.e.,  AppName_splash.png and icon-512.png while it should have been "splash.png" and "icon.png".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was fixed by removing "package-lock.json" and "npm install"

Answer (score 0):

on the config.xml file, delete everything related to android and ios platform and replace it with:

```
<platform name="android"/>
<platform name="ios"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under platform ios,

First remove all or anything similar to

```
<icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
```

Then run

1. npm i -g cordova-res
2. sudo ionic cordova resources --cordova-res

this will reload all ur resources

after this then u can build your app... works fine for me