# Cordova Android Build of icon path not found

Tags: android, cordova, cmd, phonegap

On typing `cordova build android` in a DOS box, nothing is built, but instead I see an error message:

> Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

I have updated Cordova, android rm & add everything still no luck. I am a native android developer feeling very hard to learn Cordova hybrid app development please guide me to descriptive link too.

Comment: Please refer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100060/error-source-path-does-not-exist-for-android-icon-png-when-building-for-ionic

Comment: Have your created this project with ionic ??
In your config.xml have you give the icon path as "resouces/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" ???

Comment: Yes the resource path is like this in config.xml

Comment: Project created with ionic ??

Comment: How can i check ?

Comment: easy wasy is if there is any ionic.config.json in the root of your project.

Comment: Please do not post images, and please also remove the company/product name as it might be confidential information...

Comment: I have removed inline image, and replaced it by searchable text, and in the process removed your customer name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you project is created using Ionic then do the following :-**

- Create the folder name **"resources"** in your projects root directory.
- Place your icon file name as **"icon.png"** in the resouces folder.
- Icons should be 192x192 px without rounded corners.
- Place your splash file name as  "splash.png" in the resources folder.
- Splashscreens should be 2208x2208 px, with the image centered in the
  middle.

After doing the above open you cli , go to the root of your project and enter

```
ionic cordova resources
```

your icon and splash will be generated and config file also will be updated.

**If you have created this project using cordova/phonegap :-**

- you can either remove the icon tag you specified in your config.xml completely

**or**

- create the icon and place it in "www/res/icon.png".
- Update the path in config.xml

remove all the icon path and just add this line to your config.xml

```
<icon src="www/res/icon.png"/>
```

Comment: No Luck its build with phonegap cordova

Comment: what error now ?? did you remove all icon tag from config xml ?

Comment: please add your config.xml.