# Cordova - unable to load custom icon file on Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-resources

I am developing an Android App using Cordova and Bootstrap.

I have a custom icon image that needs to replace the default Cordova icon. In my config.xml, I have specified the icon element like this:

```
... ...
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <icon src="res/helicopter.png" />
    </platform>
... ...
```

On my Windows File Explorer, I already copied the `helicopter.png` file into:

```
... ...\AASReportingCordovaApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\
```

When I tried to run the App on emulator (or run `cordova build android`, the emulator failed to start up due to the following error:

```
Updating icons at platforms\android\app\src\main\res
Source path does not exist: res/helicopter.png
Error: Source path does not exist: res/helicopter.png
```

Anything I was missing or did wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976052/cordova-android-build-of-icon-path-not-found

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the build process can't find `helicopter.png` to copy over into the target directory.

Note that you don't want to place icons and such directly in the `\platforms\...` subdirectory structure. Part of Cordova's build process is to copy images and other assets from the `\res\` subdirectory into the various platforms you support. If you edit the files in the `\platforms\` subdirectories, they are likely to get overwritten by the build.

In your case, you'll be placing the `helicopter.png` file in the `\AASReportingCordovaApp\res\` directory. There's more info in the Cordova guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html