# Error to build Ionic project - path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Hello guys Im trying to build my Ionic app but I got the following error, someone could help me? Thanks (Command used: ionic cordova build android)

```
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for android

Discovered plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage" in config.xml. Adding it to the     project

Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for android

installing external dependencies via npm
npm install of external dependencies ok
(node:31485) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Source path does not        exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png
at updatePathInternal (/home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/FileUpdater.js:145:19)
at /home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/FileUpdater.js:223:19
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.updatePaths (/home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/FileUpdater.js:221:33)
at updateIcons (/home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:387:17)
at /home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:49:9
at _fulfilled (/home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
at /home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
at /home/kill/Documents/iapp/ioo/ionic1/platforms/android/cordova /node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
(node:31485) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.    This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31485) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Source Path does not exist for android icon png when building for ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100060/error-source-path-does-not-exist-for-android-icon-png-when-building-for-ionic)

Answer (score 0):

run `ionic cordova resources` if that doesnt work the go into the resources folder delete the `ios` and `android` folders the run `ionic cordova resources` again and check to see if the files `icon.png` and `splash.png` in the `resources folder` are not corrupt.